# Which software covers these dlls?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-c++, dll

For my application, when I deployed in client OS. I see these DLL are missing(in the screenshot), can you please tell which software I need to install to make it work? 
[image: Missing DLLs]

List of Software Installed- 
[image: Installed Softwares]

I see `.net` is also installed, can you please tell what else I need to install for those missing DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Run the sfc /scannow System File Checker command to replace a missing or corrupt copy of the DLL files. [Refer this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system)